# Is it possible to wrap next-auth Provider within redux Provider?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-saga, next-auth

If I'm already using next-auth within my next.js app can I add redux around it inside _app.js somehow?

what i tried is this:

```
import React from "react"
import { Provider } from 'next-auth/client'
import {Provider as ReduxProvider} from 'react-redux';
import {configureStore} from './store/configureStore';
import '../public/styles.css'

const store = configureStore();

export default function App ({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <Provider
        // next-auth params, etc.
```

is this correct? does it work this way?
i'll also need to use redux-saga, new to the whole thing so i'm at a setup stage yet

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: Please see the answer in this other thread regarding the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65704390/wrapping-app-js-within-multiple-providers-next-react

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES. You can do that. I've tried myself and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you please share how you achieved it?