# How to wrap _app.js within multiple providers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, next-auth

I was wondering if it's possible and how to wrap my top level page `_app.js` within Redux provider considered I already wrapped it with Next-auth provider like:

```
import React from "react"
import { Provider } from 'next-auth/client'
import '../public/global.scss'

export default function App ({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <Provider
        options={{
          clientMaxAge: 0,
          keepAlive: 5 * 60
        }}
        session={pageProps.session} >
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
  )
}
```

The issue is that when I try to add also Redux `<Provider ..` it says `Provider` is already defined.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping what you're returning with the Redux provider, the same way you did with `next-auth` provider?

Comment: Yes but it says Provider is already defined

Comment: Thaks I'll try that out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rename the redux provider named import using `as`.

```js
import React from "react"
import { Provider as NextAuthProvider } from 'next-auth/client'
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux'
import '../public/global.scss'

export default function App ({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <ReduxProvider>
            <NextAuthProvider
                options={{
                    clientMaxAge: 0,
                    keepAlive: 5 * 60
                }}
                session={pageProps.session} >
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </NextAuthProvider>
        </ReduxProvider>
    )
}
```